# using OR in pycassa index expressions

Tags: python, cassandra, pycassa

Is there a way to express an **OR** operator using pycassa's `crerate_index_clause()` method? I know I could create two clauses and compare the results, but would love a solution to create only one.

Comment: I too would like to know this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra doesn't have support for disjunction at this time.

See ->
[Using operator 'or' in Cassandra IndexExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643987/using-operator-or-in-cassandra-indexexpression)